# Centering within tabular cell

Tags: tables

In the following table, how can I make the title of the second (Income Mean) and the sixth column (Social Weights) to be at the center of the cell?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,]{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=2 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=2 cm]{caption}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\usepackage{cmll}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{curves}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}% Alternative for Notes below table



\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=-1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=1 cm]{caption}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\usepackage{cmll}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{curves}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{anysize}

\usepackage{lscape}



\pagenumbering{gobble}


\title{Is Resource Constraint Satisfied Along The Equilibrium Path?}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}




% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering

\begin{adjustbox}
\scriptsize


\vspace*{-1.5cm}
\hspace*{-2.5cm}
  \begin{tabular}{llcccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ARP- Average rate progression preserving- No Behavioral Effect}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{p{5.125em}}{Income Brackets} & \multicolumn{1}{p{11.94em}}{Income Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Marginal Tax Rate} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Taxable Income Elasticities} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Income Elasticities} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.125em}}{Social Weights} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{New Marginal Tax Rate} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.375em}}{Tax Liability} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.375em}}{Change in Tax Revenue} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Transfer} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.19em}}{Change in Diposable Income} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Abatement Costs} \\
    \midrule
    0-10000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4800} & 0.10  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.84  & 0.11  & 528   & 48.00 & 428.04 & 380.04 & 985.02 \\
    10000-32000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20050} & 0.15  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 1.03  & 0.16  & 2708  & 200.50 & 438.18 & 237.68 & 596.98 \\
    32000-75000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{46200} & 0.27  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 1.01  & 0.28  & 8596  & 462.00 & 572.07 & 110.07 & 261.33 \\
    75000+ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{138100} & 0.45  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.13  & 0.46  & 45686 & 1381.00 & 653.21 & -727.79 & -1376.25 \\
    Total &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 0.00  & 467.07 \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.82} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \textbf{0.28} &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & \textbf{Abatement cost per pound} & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.25  & 0.50  & 1.00  & 1.50  & 2.00  & 2.50  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Total change in tax revenue} & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Toal abatement cost} & 0.00  & 99.49 & 248.73 & 497.46 & 994.92 & 1492.39 & 1989.85 & 2487.31 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue} & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.12  & 0.24  & 0.48  & 0.71  & 0.95  & 1.19  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Environmental MCPF} & 0.53  & 0.59  & 0.68  & 0.83  & 1.13  & 1.43  & 1.73  & 2.03  &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ARP- Average rate progression preserving}} \\
    \midrule
    0-10000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4800} & 0.10  & 0.40  & 0.10  & 0.84  & 0.11  & 525.65 & 45.65 & 301.34 & 234.36 & 607.43 \\
    10000-32000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20050} & 0.15  & 0.28  & 0.10  & 1.03  & 0.16  & 2697.28 & 189.78 & 308.49 & 51.71 & 129.89 \\
    32000-75000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{46200} & 0.27  & 0.27  & 0.10  & 1.01  & 0.28  & 8549.04 & 415.04 & 402.74 & -180.01 & -427.38 \\
    75000+ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{138100} & 0.45  & 0.48  & 0.10  & 0.13  & 0.46  & 45126.97 & 821.97 & 459.87 & -1577.38 & -2982.84 \\
    Total &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & -1471.32 & -2672.90 \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.77} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF:}} & \textbf{-0.92} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \textbf{-1.70} &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & \textbf{Abatement cost per pound} & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.25  & 0.50  & 1.00  & 1.50  & 2.00  & 2.50  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Total change in tax revenue} & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Toal abatement cost} & 0.00  & -549.53 & -1373.82 & -2747.63 & -5495.26 & -8242.90 & -10990.53 & -13738.16 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue} & 0.00  & -0.37 & -0.93 & -1.87 & -3.73 & -5.60 & -7.46 & -9.33 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Environmental MCPF} & 0.77  & 0.39  & -0.18 & -1.12 & -3.02 & -4.92 & -6.82 & -8.71 &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{LIP- Liability progression preserving}} \\
    \midrule
    0-10000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4800} & 0.10  & 0.40  & 0.10  & 0.84  & 0.10  & 484.58 & 4.58  & 59.68 & 52.96 & 137.28 \\
    10000-32000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20050} & 0.15  & 0.28  & 0.10  & 1.03  & 0.15  & 2531.05 & 23.55 & 61.10 & 27.50 & 69.06 \\
    32000-75000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{46200} & 0.27  & 0.27  & 0.10  & 1.01  & 0.27  & 8202.99 & 68.99 & 79.77 & -34.51 & -81.93 \\
    75000+ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{138100} & 0.45  & 0.48  & 0.10  & 0.13  & 0.45  & 44499.49 & 194.49 & 91.08 & -650.29 & -1229.71 \\
    Total &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 291.62 & 291.62 & -604.34 & -1105.30 \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.99} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF:}} & \textbf{-4.09} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \textbf{-5.08} &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & \textbf{Abatement cost per pound} & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.25  & 0.50  & 1.00  & 1.50  & 2.00  & 2.50  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Total change in tax revenue} & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Toal abatement cost} & 0.00  & -227.30 & -568.24 & -1136.48 & -2272.96 & -3409.44 & -4545.92 & -5682.39 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue} & 0.00  & -0.78 & -1.95 & -3.90 & -7.79 & -11.69 & -15.59 & -19.49 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Environmental MCPF} & 0.99  & -0.06 & -1.62 & -4.24 & -9.46 & -14.68 & -19.91 & -25.13 &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%

 \end{adjustbox}

\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a [MWE](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html), please simplify!

Comment: However, does a simple `\centering` help? E. g. `\multicolumn{1}{p{4.125em}}{\centering Social Weights}`.

Answer (score 1):

I removed a lot of extraneous excrement but it sounds like you want something like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperwidth=11in,paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\pagenumbering{gobble}


\title{Is Resource Constraint Satisfied Along The Equilibrium Path?}

\begin{document}






% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'

%
\tiny
  \begin{tabular}{llcccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ARP- Average rate progression preserving- No Behavioral Effect}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{p{5.125em}}{Income Brackets} & \multicolumn{1}{p{11.94em}}{Income Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Marginal Tax Rate} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Taxable Income Elasticities} & \parbox{5.19em}{Income Elasticities\centering} & \parbox{4.25em}{Social Weights\centering} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{New Marginal Tax Rate} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.375em}}{Tax Liability} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.375em}}{Change in Tax Revenue} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Transfer} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.19em}}{Change in Diposable Income} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.19em}}{Abatement Costs} \\
    \midrule
    0-10000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4800} & 0.10  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.84  & 0.11  & 528   & 48.00 & 428.04 & 380.04 & 985.02 \\
    10000-32000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20050} & 0.15  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 1.03  & 0.16  & 2708  & 200.50 & 438.18 & 237.68 & 596.98 \\
    32000-75000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{46200} & 0.27  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 1.01  & 0.28  & 8596  & 462.00 & 572.07 & 110.07 & 261.33 \\
    75000+ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{138100} & 0.45  & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.13  & 0.46  & 45686 & 1381.00 & 653.21 & -727.79 & -1376.25 \\
    Total &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 0.00  & 467.07 \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.53} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.82} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \textbf{0.28} &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & \textbf{Abatement cost per pound} & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.25  & 0.50  & 1.00  & 1.50  & 2.00  & 2.50  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Total change in tax revenue} & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Toal abatement cost} & 0.00  & 99.49 & 248.73 & 497.46 & 994.92 & 1492.39 & 1989.85 & 2487.31 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue} & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.12  & 0.24  & 0.48  & 0.71  & 0.95  & 1.19  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Environmental MCPF} & 0.53  & 0.59  & 0.68  & 0.83  & 1.13  & 1.43  & 1.73  & 2.03  &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ARP- Average rate progression preserving}} \\
    \midrule
    0-10000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4800} & 0.10  & 0.40  & 0.10  & 0.84  & 0.11  & 525.65 & 45.65 & 301.34 & 234.36 & 607.43 \\
    10000-32000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20050} & 0.15  & 0.28  & 0.10  & 1.03  & 0.16  & 2697.28 & 189.78 & 308.49 & 51.71 & 129.89 \\
    32000-75000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{46200} & 0.27  & 0.27  & 0.10  & 1.01  & 0.28  & 8549.04 & 415.04 & 402.74 & -180.01 & -427.38 \\
    75000+ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{138100} & 0.45  & 0.48  & 0.10  & 0.13  & 0.46  & 45126.97 & 821.97 & 459.87 & -1577.38 & -2982.84 \\
    Total &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & -1471.32 & -2672.90 \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.77} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF:}} & \textbf{-0.92} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \textbf{-1.70} &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & \textbf{Abatement cost per pound} & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.25  & 0.50  & 1.00  & 1.50  & 2.00  & 2.50  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Total change in tax revenue} & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Toal abatement cost} & 0.00  & -549.53 & -1373.82 & -2747.63 & -5495.26 & -8242.90 & -10990.53 & -13738.16 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue} & 0.00  & -0.37 & -0.93 & -1.87 & -3.73 & -5.60 & -7.46 & -9.33 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Environmental MCPF} & 0.77  & 0.39  & -0.18 & -1.12 & -3.02 & -4.92 & -6.82 & -8.71 &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{LIP- Liability progression preserving}} \\
    \midrule
    0-10000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4800} & 0.10  & 0.40  & 0.10  & 0.84  & 0.10  & 484.58 & 4.58  & 59.68 & 52.96 & 137.28 \\
    10000-32000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20050} & 0.15  & 0.28  & 0.10  & 1.03  & 0.15  & 2531.05 & 23.55 & 61.10 & 27.50 & 69.06 \\
    32000-75000 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{46200} & 0.27  & 0.27  & 0.10  & 1.01  & 0.27  & 8202.99 & 68.99 & 79.77 & -34.51 & -81.93 \\
    75000+ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{138100} & 0.45  & 0.48  & 0.10  & 0.13  & 0.45  & 44499.49 & 194.49 & 91.08 & -650.29 & -1229.71 \\
    Total &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 291.62 & 291.62 & -604.34 & -1105.30 \\
          &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{MCPF:}} & \textbf{0.99} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF:}} & \textbf{-4.09} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \textbf{-5.08} &       &       &  \\
\cmidrule{2-10}          & \textbf{Abatement cost per pound} & 0.00  & 0.10  & 0.25  & 0.50  & 1.00  & 1.50  & 2.00  & 2.50  &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Total change in tax revenue} & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Toal abatement cost} & 0.00  & -227.30 & -568.24 & -1136.48 & -2272.96 & -3409.44 & -4545.92 & -5682.39 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue} & 0.00  & -0.78 & -1.95 & -3.90 & -7.79 & -11.69 & -15.59 & -19.49 &       &  \\
          & \textbf{Environmental MCPF} & 0.99  & -0.06 & -1.62 & -4.24 & -9.46 & -14.68 & -19.91 & -25.13 &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `sidewaystable` (from the `rotating` package) preferably to `landscape`+`table` here. In addition, the `S` column type from `siunitx` to align numbers on the decimal dot, and `makecell` for the colum heads (alllows to break lines in cells`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, margin=1 cm]{caption}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, rotating}
\usepackage{etoolbox, siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--, table-number-alignment=center, detect-weight}
\robustify\bfseries
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{anysize}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{Is Resource Constraint Satisfied Along The Equilibrium Path?}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize\bfseries}
  \scriptsize
  \vspace*{-0.7cm}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=6.0]*{2}{S[table-format=-3.2]}*{4}{S[table-format=-4.2]}*{2}{S[table-format=-5.2]}*{2}{S[table-format=-4.2]}@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ARP--Average rate progression preserving--No Behavioral Effect}} \\
    \midrule
    \makecell{Income \\ Brackets} &{\makecell{Income\\ Mean}} &% \multicolumn{1}{c}p{11.94em}
    {\makecell[lc]{Marginal \\ Tax Rate}} & {\makecell{Taxable\\ Income\\ Elasticities}} & {\makecell{Income\\ Elasticities}} &{Social Weights} &
    {\makecell{New \\ Marginal\\ Tax Rate}} & {\makecell{Tax\\ Liability}} & {\makecell{Change in\\ Tax Revenue}} & {Transfer} & {\makecell{Change in\\ Disposable\\ Income}} & {\makecell{Abatement\\ Costs}} \\
    \midrule
    \numrange{0}{10000} & 4800 & 0.10 & 0.00 & 0.10 & 0.84 & 0.11 & 528 & 48.00 & 428.04 & 380.04 & 985.02 \\
    \numrange{10000}{32000} & 20050 & 0.15 & 0.00 & 0.10 & 1.03 & 0.16 & 2708 & 200.50 & 438.18 & 237.68 & 596.98 \\
    \numrange{32000}{75000} & 46200 & 0.27 & 0.00 & 0.10 & 1.01 & 0.28 & 8596 & 462.00 & 572.07 & 110.07 & 261.33 \\
    75000+ & 138100 & 0.45 & 0.00 & 0.10 & 0.13 & 0.46 & 45686 & 1381.00 & 653.21 & -727.79 & -1376.25 \\
    Total & & & & & & & & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 0.00 & 467.07 \\[-2ex]
                                                                                     & & & {\textbf{MCPF:}} & \bfseries 0.53 & {\thead{\clap{Environmental} \\ MCPF:}}& \bfseries 0.82 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \bfseries .28 & & & \\[-1.5ex]
    \cmidrule(lr){3-10}%
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{ \textbf{Abatement cost per pound}} & 0.00 & 0.10 & 0.25 & 0.50 & 1.00 & 1.50 & 2.00 & 2.50 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Total change in tax revenue}} & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & 2091.50 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Total abatement cost}} & 0.00 & 99.49 & 248.73 & 497.46 & 994.92 & 1492.39 & 1989.85 & 2487.31 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue}} & 0.00 & 0.05 & 0.12 & 0.24 & 0.48 & 0.71 & 0.95 & 1.19 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF}} & 0.53 & 0.59 & 0.68 & 0.83 & 1.13 & 1.43 & 1.73 & 2.03 & & \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ARP--Average rate progression preserving}} \\
    \midrule
    \numrange{0}{10000} & 4800 & 0.10 & 0.40 & 0.10 & 0.84 & 0.11 & 525.65 & 45.65 & 301.34 & 234.36 & 607.43 \\
    \numrange{10000}{32000} & 20050 & 0.15 & 0.28 & 0.10 & 1.03 & 0.16 & 2697.28 & 189.78 & 308.49 & 51.71 & 129.89 \\
    \numrange{32000}{75000} & 46200 & 0.27 & 0.27 & 0.10 & 1.01 & 0.28 & 8549.04 & 415.04 & 402.74 & -180.01 & -427.38 \\
    75000+ & 138100 & 0.45 & 0.48 & 0.10 & 0.13 & 0.46 & 45126.97 & 821.97 & 459.87 & -1577.38 & -2982.84 \\
    Total & & & & & & & & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & -1471.32 & -2672.90 \\[-2ex]
                                                                                     & & & {\textbf{MCPF:}} & \bfseries 0.77 & {\thead{\clap{Environmental} \\MCPF:}} & \bfseries -0.92 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \bfseries-1.70 & & & \\[-1.5ex]
    \cmidrule(lr){3-10} \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{ \textbf{Abatement cost per pound}} & 0.00 & 0.10 & 0.25 & 0.50 & 1.00 & 1.50 & 2.00 & 2.50 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Total change in tax revenue}} & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & 1472.45 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Total abatement cost}} & 0.00 & -549.53 & -1373.82 & -2747.63 & -5495.26 & -8242.90 & -10990.53 & -13738.16 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue}} & 0.00 & -0.37 & -0.93 & -1.87 & -3.73 & -5.60 & -7.46 & -9.33 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Environmental MCPF}} & 0.77 & 0.39 & -0.18 & -1.12 & -3.02 & -4.92 & -6.82 & -8.71 & & \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{LIP--Liability progression preserving}} \\
    \midrule
    \numrange{0}{10000} & 4800 & 0.10 & 0.40 & 0.10 & 0.84 & 0.10 & 484.58 & 4.58 & 59.68 & 52.96 & 137.28 \\
    \numrange{10000}{32000} & 20050 & 0.15 & 0.28 & 0.10 & 1.03 & 0.15 & 2531.05 & 23.55 & 61.10 & 27.50 & 69.06 \\
    \numrange{32000}{75000} & 46200 & 0.27 & 0.27 & 0.10 & 1.01 & 0.27 & 8202.99 & 68.99 & 79.77 & -34.51 & -81.93 \\
    75000+ & 138100 & 0.45 & 0.48 & 0.10 & 0.13 & 0.45 & 44499.49 & 194.49 & 91.08 & -650.29 & -1229.71 \\
    Total & & & & & & & & 291.62 & 291.62 & -604.34 & -1105.30 \\[-2ex]
                                                                                     & & & {\textbf{MCPF:}} & \bfseries 0.99 & {\thead{\clap{Environmental} \\ MCPF:}} & \bfseries -4.09 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Difference:}} & \bfseries-5.08 & & & \\[-1.5ex]
    \cmidrule(lr){3-10}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Abatement cost per pound}} & 0.00 & 0.10 & 0.25 & 0.50 & 1.00 & 1.50 & 2.00 & 2.50 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Total change in tax revenue}} & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & 291.62 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Total abatement cost}} & 0.00 & -227.30 & -568.24 & -1136.48 & -2272.96 & -3409.44 & -4545.92 & -5682.39 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Abatement cost/Tax revenue}} & 0.00 & -0.78 & -1.95 & -3.90 & -7.79 & -11.69 & -15.59 & -19.49 & & \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{ \textbf{Environmental MCPF}} & 0.99 & -0.06 & -1.62 & -4.24 & -9.46 & -14.68 & -19.91 & -25.13 & & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]